# How to use multiprocessing to create threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I was trying to use Process to create threads in python.

But it keeps showing errors.

And here is my code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading

class OneProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.workers = []
        for i in range(5):
            worker = OneThread()
            self.workers.append(worker)

    def run(self):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.start()
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()


class OneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("do somethings")

class Shell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_process = OneProcess()

    def start(self):
        self.first_process.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell = Shell()
    shell.start()
```

And here is the error:

```
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I guess it just can't serilize the thread object?
So is there any method can achieve this?
Or using Process to create threads is unavaliable in python?

Comment: Create your thread objects inside the `run()` method instead of in the `__init__`

Comment: @rdas You should write your comment up as an answer with an explanation (if you have one) -- it would be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping that @rdas would turn his comment into an actual answer. Since nothing has been forthcoming, I will answer as best I can:

Your code actually works under Linux. So I am guessing you are running under Windows (I don't know enough about other environments, such as the Mac). The threads are being created within the `__init__` method of class `OneProcess`, which is executed under the same process as the main process. This is demonstrated in the modified code below. But when the statement `self.first_process.start()` is executed causing the `OneProcess.run()` to be called, we are now running is the subprocess and therefore the internal state of the `OnceProcess` object has to be transferred over to the new subprocess using `pickle`, and this is where the error occurs. By moving the creation of the threads to the `run` method, there is no thread-related state to be pickled.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import os

class OneProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('OneProcess __init__:', os.getpid())


    def run(self):
        print('OneProcess run:', os.getpid())
        self.workers = []
        for i in range(5):
            worker = OneThread()
            self.workers.append(worker)
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.start()
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.join()


class OneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("do somethings")

class Shell():
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_process = OneProcess()

    def start(self):
        self.first_process.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('main pid:', os.getpid())
    shell = Shell()
    shell.start()
```

Prints:

```
main pid: 25208
OneProcess __init__: 25208
OneProcess run: 18912
do somethings
do somethings
do somethings
do somethings
do somethings
```

Why does your original code works in Linux? This has to do with Linux supporting the OS [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) call, which copies the entire process when creating a new subprocess and therefore does not have to rely on using `pickle` to transfer the state. See [What is being pickled when I call multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025878/what-is-being-pickled-when-i-call-multiprocessing-process)