# why spawn method is much slower than fork method in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, fork, python-multiprocessing

I was experimenting different starting methods in *multiprocessing* module and I found something weird. Changing the variable `method` from `"spawn"` to `"fork"`, drops the execution time from `9.5` to just `0.5`.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from time import time


def increment_value(shared_integer):
    with shared_integer.get_lock():
        shared_integer.value += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    method = "spawn"
    mp.set_start_method(method)

    start = time()
    for _ in range(200):
        integer = Value("i", 0)
        procs = [
            Process(target=increment_value, args=(integer,)),
            Process(target=increment_value, args=(integer,)),
        ]

        for p in procs:
            p.start()
        for p in procs:
            p.join()

        assert integer.value == 2

    print(f"{method} - Finished in {time() - start:.4f} seconds")
```

outputs for different runs:

```
spawn - Finished in 9.4275 seconds
fork - Finished in 0.5316 seconds
```

I'm aware of how these two methods start a new child process(well-explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806714/determining-exactly-what-is-pickled-during-python-multiprocessing)), but this difference puts a big question mark in my head. I would like know exactly which part of the code impacts the performance mostly? Is that the pickling part in `"spawn"`? Does it have anything to do with the lock?

I'm running this code on Linux Pop!_OS and my interpreter version is 3.11.

Comment: Did you happen to see: [multiprocessing fork() vs spawn()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095876/multiprocessing-fork-vs-spawn)? (duplicate?)

Comment: @JonSG Yes I did. So is it just the starting method that is much slower? I don't know why I didn't expect this number and I guessed there must be something else as well.

Comment: I don't actually know myself. I just have read that post a few times in the past while helping people debug spawn/fork problems on windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing fork() vs spawn()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095876/multiprocessing-fork-vs-spawn)

Comment: Your processes are doing basically no work at all; your total time is dominated by the startup time of each process - which is indeed higher for spawn vs. fork.  You wouldn't see this magnitude of difference in any realistic use of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fork method copies all resources from a process and continues from that point, whereas the spawn method creates a new instance of the Python interpreter and recreates that point (by "point" I mean the state of the process: what resources it has, etc).

As you can imagine, simply copying some data has a lot less overhead than creating an entirely new Python process and recreating all of that data, and thus it is much quicker.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was overthinking and I made it complicated. Creating a new python interpreter and importing the module in a loop is "*that*" costly.